# Options to preserver state of file and continue working with it

Tags: perforce

Suppose I've made some changes to a bunch of files and sent the changelist for review. The review may take up to 24 hours. During that time I might need to edit some of the files in the changelist, but when review is over, I'll need to be able to get back to the version of the file in the approved changelist. What options do I currently have to do that in Perforce?

One option that comes to mind is stashing the files and then reverting when needed, but in this way I'll lose the changes done on top of the stashed versions.

I've read about using task streams, is it something that can help me handle that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the files have been shelved in the changelist for review (as opposed to emailing them off or using some other review mechanism).  If so, I'd move the open files to another changelist:

```
p4 change
p4 reopen -c (new change) (files)
```

and continue working on them.  The shelved versions of the files will stay in the old changelist.

If you need to go back to the old changelist, shelve your new changelist:

```
p4 shelve -c (new change)
```

and then revert your open files (they should be safe in the new shelved changelist now) and unshelve the old changelist to keep working from that point:

```
p4 revert (files)
p4 unshelve -s (old change)
```

There are lots of variations on this you could do, such as reverting and starting over from scratch rather than building your newer changes on top of the changes that are currently under review.  If you do that, you'll need to merge the changes later, but Perforce will track all of that automatically and prompt you when it's time (as long as you're using Perforce commands to sync/revert/unshelve/etc -- if you start making your own backups and restoring them manually all bets are off because Perforce doesn't know what your edits are based on any more and can't guide you through the merge process intelligently).

Comment: thanks, do you know if the task streams can have some benefits here? I'm trying to find something similar to local branches in git

Comment: Task streams would be useful if you had a consecutive series of changes that you needed to isolate from the stream you're working on; from your description it sounds like we're only talking about individual independent changes so having them as shelves (rather than versioned in branches) is sufficient, but a task stream would be the way to version them on a shared server.  You could also of course clone a local/personal server with "p4 clone" and create local streams there before pushing back to the shared server.